Is it possible to have a page which requires a password to redirect to the website?
If it is possible how would I do it?
To elaborate I mean a page which requires a password and once you enter it the page is redirected to the website.

I am currently hosting and working on the website on GitHub pages. Would it work here?

Yes, it's possible.  Though the security it provides is questionable.  If the page to which the user is redirected has no security measure in place then there's nothing to stop a user from just bookmarking that page or sharing that URL, which would entirely bypass the password.  As for GitHub pages... My understanding is that they only host static resources and offer no server-side functionality.  Which means any such password "protection" would be in client-side functionality and easily ignored/bypassed.

Yes, it is possible to create a page that requires a password to redirect to another website. However, you'd better consider something, especially when hosting on GitHub Pages.
The password can be easily found by viewing the page source or inspecting the network requests.
Anyone can share the direct URL of the target site, bypassing the password protection.
If you need more robust security, consider using a hosting service that supports server-side code or using a web framework that provides built-in authentication and authorization features.
